# Python understanding structure and global variables

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm quite new to python and I need some advice.

This how I organized and wrote my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ...

exitCode = 1   

def sendmail(mess,type): 
    [...]
    if ...
       exitCode = 9
    else
       exitCode = 1

    [...]
    return 0

#=====
#start

[...]

try:
    [...]

except:  
    sendmail(message,"connect")
    sys.exit(exitCode)

sys.exit(0)
```

1. import part
2. variables definition
3. function sendmail
4. start (should be my main) which contains some sets of `try/except` and `if/else`

I would like to understand a couple of things:

1. Did I structured my script in the correct way? I did not understand how is the main function defined, sometimes it is used, sometimes not... what should be the best to do?
2. In the "main" at a certain point `sendmail` function is called, which, if something goes wrong, sets the variable `exitCode` to 9. Than further processing is done and it returns 0. Now `exitCode` is defined at the very top so I expect to be a global variable. But if I read it's value in the except (soon after the `sendmail`) it's value is "1" while I expect a "9". if I read it in the `sendmail` function the value is correctly "9". What am I doing wrong? I think I could use `return exitCode` instead of `return 0`, but I would like to understand the mistake.

Comment: [Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).  [Naming and Binding](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The best thing is to use

   ```
   if __name__ == "__main__":
   ```

as a main entry point to your code (see explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)).

2. To address a variable on the global scope, you should precede it with:

   ```
   global exitCode
   ```

However, using global variables is generally discouraged. In your case, it may be better to set the return value of the `sendmail()` function to be the exit code, so it will look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ...

def sendmail(mess,type): 
    [...]
    if ...
       exitCode = 9
    else
       exitCode = 1

    [...]
    return exitCode

#=====
#start

[...]

try:
    [...]

except:  
    exitCode = sendmail(message,"connect")
    sys.exit(exitCode)

sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will modify the code accordingly and try! Thank you also for the link!

Answer (score 1):

There are two different `exitCode`s in your code. The one in the global scope, which you assign just after `import`; and the one inside `sendmail`. Modifying one will have no effect on the other. If you want to modify the global `exitCode` from within the function, use the `global` statement.

```
def sendmail(mess,type): 
    global exitCode
    [...]
```